# How to access the reference of an array element (read & write the element of an array)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, referenceerror

I am trying to basically being able to access a specific element of an array in order to read it or to change it (thus the reference idea).

Sure, `array[i][j]` is the solution.

But I am trying to basically access this element with a specific ID for each element.

Let me show you what I am trying to achieve :
I want to access `chessboard[0][0]` with `chessboard.square("a8")` and be able to change the value or read it. Each element of my 2D array has an unique id (the chess coordinates, here a8 for [0][0]) and I would find it more convenient to access the element with this ID rather than write the actual array coordinates.

```
     
     square(coordinate) {
        const {row, col} = this.parseSquareToBoard(coordinate)  
        return this.chessboard[row][col]
     }
     /* the function parseSquareToBoard is used to get the coordinates of the array from the string id (for example parseSquareToBoard("a8") returns {col: 0, row: 0} */


     printBoard() {
        this.square('a1') = "R " // this is the line where I obviously get a ReferenceError
        this.chessboard.map(row => {
            row.map(piece => process.stdout.write(piece ? piece : "X "))
            console.log()
        })
     }
```

All that is inside a class.
Any idea of what I could do to be able to do so ?
Please let me know if my question needs clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Just create a lookup table? `{a1: {piece: 'R', row: 0, col:0}...}`. You can store the assigned object as a reference in the `board` array and they will update on mutation.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `square` method:

```
const { row, col } = this.parseSquareToBoard(coordinate);

this.chessboard[row][col] = "R ";
```

If you really want to avoid using `array[i][j]`, make a helper method:

```
setSquare(coordinate, piece) {
    const { row, col } = this.parseSquareToBoard(coordinate);

    this.chessboard[row][col] = piece;
}

// ...

printBoard() {
    this.setSquare("a8", "R ");
    // ...
}
```